# How to automate overhangs generation with meshmixer python API?

Tags: python, 3d-printing

I'm trying to automate the 'overhangs generation' for 3Dprinting, with a given STL and meshmixer software, I'm currently able to use 'test.py' successfully with a previously opened meshmixer, it properly cuts the bunny model, (source: https://github.com/meshmixer/mm-api)

but i'm struggling with the doc to be able to modify script and 'automatically generate overhangs':

trying to find help into this doc: https://github.com/meshmixer/mm-api/blob/master/distrib/python/StoredCommands.h

```py
#coding: utf-8
#for python 2.7 (32bits) and autodesk meshmixer 3.0 (3.5 seems to work not so bad)
# please note that you need to have meshmixer software launched, and import 'bunny' model first

import os, subprocess, shutil, time

import mmapi from mmRemote import *;

#initialize connection
remote = mmRemote(); remote.connect();
#construct commands to run
cmd = mmapi.StoredCommands()

cmd.AppendBeginToolCommand("overhangs")
remote.runCommand(cmd); # execute commands

cmd.AppendCompleteToolCommand("accept")
remote.runCommand(cmd); # execute commands

remote.shutdown();

print("done.")
```

thx by advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

okay: I find a way with the following:

adding a path pointing to the python package 'mm' for python2

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('D:/Tools/meshmixer_mmApi_python2')
import mm
```

thanks to:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dIJXIhTvk93as15j-DUMJtwE8P_eyGkM
(or build it by yourself)

then

```py
import mmapi from mmRemote import *;

# initialize connection
remote = mmRemote();
remote.connect();
mm.begin_tool(remote, "overhangs")
mm.tool_utility_command(remote, "generateSupport")
mm.accept_tool(remote)

#done !
remote.shutdown();
```

(Actually, it's in the 'examples' folder..)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33505171)

Comment: it's the complete answers, I think.